# Efficiently use mysql Table to cache complex queries

Tags: php, mysql, query-cache

I used to have quite a big number of multiple Joins in queries.

To be able to use (at least) the build-in MySql Cache features I wrote the following function,
it simply encodes the original query into base64, checks if it's there and not expired.

This has improved the performance dramatically, and I have the advantage to contol the cache-time query-by-query in the source code.

But on busy times the table becomes unavailable due to deletions or the selections simply take too long.  Are there any suggestion on what to do to make this run faster and to avoid the problem previous mentioned?

table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cachesql` (
`id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`expire` int(15) NOT NULL,
`sql` text NOT NULL,
`data` mediumtext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`sql`(360)),
KEY `sdata` (`sql`(767)) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

function:

```
    function fetchRows_cache($sql,$cachetime,$dba){
    // internal function (called by fetchRows)
    global $Site;
    $expire = 0;
    $this->connect($dba);

    // check if query is cached
    $this->q = mysql_query("SELECT `expire`,`data` from cachesql where `sql`='".base64_encode($sql)."' limit 1;", $this->con) OR $this->error(1, "query$".$sql."$".mysql_error());
    $this->r = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->q);
    $expire = $this->r['expire'];
    $data = $this->r['data'];

    if (($expire < time())||($cachetime =="0")) { // record expied or not there -> execute query and store
        $this->query("DELETE FROM `cachesql` WHERE `sql`='".base64_encode($sql)."'",$dba); // delete old cached entries

        $this->q = mysql_query($sql, $this->con) OR $this->error(1, "query$".$sql."$".mysql_error());
        $this->r=array();
        $this->rc=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->q)){
            $arr_row=array();
            $c=0;
            while ($c < mysql_num_fields($this->q)) {        
                $col = mysql_fetch_field($this->q, $c);    
                $arr_row[$col -> name] = $row[$col -> name];            
                $c++;
            }    
            $this->r[$this->rc] = $arr_row;
            $this->rc++;
        }
        $out = $this->r;

        // write results into cache table
        if ($cachetime != "0") {
            // not store cache values for now (too many locks)
            $this->query("INSERT INTO `cachesql` (`sql`,`data`,`expire`) VALUES ('".base64_encode($sql)."','".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($out))."','".(time()+$cachetime)."')",$dba);       
        }
        return $out;

    }
    else { // use Cached data
        return unserialize($data); 
    }
}
```

Comment: since sql is a text field it can't be really used as primary key. same goes for Memory tables, also VarChar field for SQL is not exactly possible since the queries can be MUCH longer then 256 Bytes.

Comment: i had the idea to just store checksums in a varchar field instead of the full query, but i dont know if that is such a smart idea after all ... any thoughts ?

Comment: By checksum, do you mean MD5 or other such hash code?  MD5 has cryptography issues, but should be fine for your purpose.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn with checksum i mean anything can identify the original query in a very short referal, perfect would be nummeric so i could store this instead of the original query and set the primary index to the `sql` field instead (well that was the idea, i also not sure if MD5 will do that in a fast manner, since i wont decode (ever) it could be any form of checksum generation (as faster as better)

Comment: How about using memcached instead?

Comment: @nullx8: varchar can be up to 64k long since 5.0.3. however, indexes on a varchar that big will be pretty slow.

Comment: i sorted this out with a very short Checksum stored instead... the fetch times are extremly fast now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @HeatfanJohn - he pointet out something really Simple and efficient.

since the original Queries are not used for anything (except the matching of cache entries),
it is enough to simply store a checksum identify the query in question uniquely.

the new structure simply stores the MD5 hash of the original Query (16 Bytes), expireUnixTime , and the serialized row-set

new Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `cachesql` (
`sql` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`expire` int(11) NOT NULL,
`data` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`sql`),
UNIQUE KEY `sql` (`sql`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='cache for db->fetchRows'
```

The primary index on the `sql` column reacts extremely fast since its very short, and can be indexed for searches much better.

I have not get a different speed results in using BLOB or TEXT fields for the datasets.

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please mark it as answered with the check to the left of your answer. If not, please edit your question and add the additional info, then delete the answer. Thanks.

Comment: i have tried the same with a Binary field but the matching takes then much longer. using a varchar(32) seems to be the best and fastest solution to store the md5 hash.

Answer (score 0):

i think the main slowing down point is, that you use InnoDB for your caching table.

i found out, that you should use InnoDB for everything except for read-heavy cache-tables ;)

MyISAM is especially good for read-intensive (select) tables.

Comment: MyISAM is fast because it is a nontransactional storage engine. But if you need transactions and full ACID compliance you should not use it.

Comment: agree ! MyISAM has a huge Downside on Locking issues. since the table is populated by temporary data and the cleanup is done in the same process, using MyISAM would Lock the Table basically forever, the Data is read about 50-100 times until expired so the DELETE command do still over 1% of the transactions  MyISAM -> Bad Choice !

Answer (score 0):

Lets try the inmemory table to make it faster.

Comment: Memory tables do not support Text fileds and for large row results the 64K varchar size is not enough